# How to filter out certain keys in a map in Trino/Presto?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a column which is a map with key value pairs per row and i would like to filter out some keys that I do not care about such that the resultant map is a filtered version per row.

The keys that I care about will be in an array though which should be sorted. How can I use that array of keys along with an IN operator so I can use map_filter function or is there any other way to fetch the map per row using perhaps element_at function. I did not find anything in the documentation.

So far I have this SQL query:

```
    WITH temp AS (
    SELECT array_sort(filter(map_keys(mapColumn), x -> x not in ('id', 'image')))) as myFiltered 
FROM myTable WHERE myFilter = 'a'
    )     
    SELECT map_filter(mapColumn,(k, v) -> k in temp.myFiltered))) from myTable WHERE myFilter = 'a'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly - you need to use [`contains`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains) array function:

```sql
select map_filter(m, (k, v) -> contains(array[1], k)) filtered
from (values (map(array[2,1], array['b', 'a']))) as t(m);
```

Output:

```
 filtered
----------
 {1=a}
```

Or if you need to filter out some keys - then `not contains`:

```sql
select map_filter(m, (k, v) -> not contains(array[1], k)) filtered
from (values (map(array[2,1], array['b', 'a']))) as t(m);
```

Output:

```
 filtered
----------
 {2=b}
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response. I updated the question to make it clear the original table and result table that I am looking for not contains ie I want to take a map, get rid of some keys then sort the map by remaining keys. My approach was to take map keys, remove the keys i dont care about then sort rest of map keys and then i was thinking of somehow indexing into the map for those sorted keys and get a resultant map but could not get it to work. Hope that explains the original problem. I see you also answered by other question so we cannot use ordered map.

Comment: @arjunj you can't use the sorted map because there is no such concept in Trino/Presto) By the way, what are you using, Presto or Trino? And why do you need the ordered map, maybe it will make more sense to flatten the map into columns?

Comment: I am using Trino. So the reason to think of sorting the map was to get the unique values combination of bunch of keys that i care about. problem is my source map is not ordered so x=1 can be in any position in the map. I updated the question with my eventual end goal. I just want unique value combination of keys (x,y,z) by doing not in (p,q) or something like that

Comment: you update to the question changes it a lot, the original question was pretty concise and matched the header, and the answer was perfectly fine for it. I suggest to revert the edit and close this one as answered and move the discussion to the second question.

Comment: @arjunj feel free to accept the answer if it covers the question =))

Comment: So for this question you are suggesting using contains, but I want to exclude key=1 so the filtered should be 2=b. So how to do the opposite? thanks again

Comment: @arjunj as usual in SQL - using `not` i.e. `(k, v) -> not contains(...)`

Comment: Thought so :) but i was not sure if i can update the answer but if you edit it, i can mark as accepted